# EditText not taking input in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I have one edittext

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/selectvalue"
            style="@style/searchList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="@string/search_order_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="@color/common_gray"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
```

I have attached TextWatcher to this.

```
            selectedValue.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                showKeyBoard(mContext, selectedValue);
                return false;
            }
        });

        selectedValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
          
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!selectedAssetType.equals(OrderBookTypes.MUTUAL_FUND_TYPE)) {
                    loadSearchFilterData();
                }
            }
        });

    public void showKeyBoard(Context context, EditText edit) {
    InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (m != null) {
        edit.requestFocus();
        m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}

  private void loadSearchFilterData() {

    if (!selectedValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        String s = selectedValue.getText().toString();
        List<BoOrderBookDao> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedFilteredList.size(); i++) {
            if (sortedFilteredList.get(i).getDpVal().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())) {
                filterList.add(sortedFilteredList.get(i));
            }
        }
        orderBookModel.clear();
        orderBookModel.addAll(filterList);
    } else {
        orderBookModel.clear();
        orderBookModel.addAll(sortedFilteredList);
    }

    if (orderBookModel.size() == 0) {
        setErrorMsg(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.no_data_available_txt));
    } else {
        itemListLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        errorScrollview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (orderAdapter != null) {
        orderAdapter.requestType = requestType;
        orderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

But I can not type there. Charaters are not shown when I type. If I remove  `orderBookModel.addAll(filterList);` line then I can type but removing the line will break my functionality. Who can solve this?

Comment: Where is the `orderBookModel.addAll(filterList);` line in your code?

Comment: Okay, I missed to add the method. I have updated the code. See now.

Answer (score 0):

Add   orderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after adding data in orderBookModel.

Update code replace this code:

```
 private void loadSearchFilterData() {

if (!selectedValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    String s = selectedValue.getText().toString();
    List<BoOrderBookDao> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedFilteredList.size(); i++) {
        if (sortedFilteredList.get(i).getDpVal().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())) {
            filterList.add(sortedFilteredList.get(i));
        }
    }
    orderBookModel.clear();
    orderBookModel.addAll(filterList);
     orderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Add this
} else {
    orderBookModel.clear();
    orderBookModel.addAll(sortedFilteredList);
    orderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Add this
}

if (orderBookModel.size() == 0) {
    setErrorMsg(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.no_data_available_txt));
} else {
    itemListLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    errorScrollview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
if (orderAdapter != null) {
    orderAdapter.requestType = requestType;
    orderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Harshil for your effor. But the problem still exist.